# Modify content of a column based on the data present in other columns

Tags: sql, group-by, google-bigquery

The data I have looks like below-

```
category_id  category  Type_1    Type_2    no_of_items
   123         cat_A      A       both         5
   123         cat_A      B       both         10
   123         cat_B      B       both         35
   123         cat_B      A       both         10
   123         cat_C      A       both         20
```

I want to achieve the following result-

When category_id, category is SAME and Type_2 is 'both' (there are many other types in Type_2)-

check if Type_1 has a record with A and B and if it does then change Type_1 to 'both' **otherwise keep it as it is** and sum the no_of_items.

If Type_1 has a record with either A or B then keep Type_1 as it is.

The result should look like-

```
category_id  category  Type_1    Type_2    no_of_items
   123        cat_A    both       both         15
   123        cat_B    both       both         45
   123        cat_C      A        both         20
```

Comment: Please add more sample data which would help to better explain your aggregation logic.

Comment: Your data only shows the cases where aggregation occurs. You need to provide some data which shows your expected results when the conditions for aggregation are **not** met.

Comment: @Nick updated the question. When the conditions for aggregation are not met that means both A and B are not present, either A or B is present in which case I want to keep the Type_1 as it is and not aggregate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get you correctly then following query will work by doing `sum(no_of_items)`. Here is the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nj5UgvFQQR5VAkjo3npyhg/0) in postgres but same solution should work for BigQuery.

```
select
    category_id,
    category,
    case when total = 2 then 'both' else Type_1 end as Type_1,
    Type_2,
    sum(no_of_items) as no_of_items
from
(select
    category_id,
    category,
    Type_1,
    Type_2,
    no_of_items,
    count(Type_1) over (partition by category) as total
from category
) t
group by
    category_id,
    category,
    case when total = 2 then 'both' else Type_1 end,
    Type_2
order by
    category
```

Output:

```
----------------------------------------------------
category_id category    type_1  type_2  no_of_items
----------------------------------------------------
    123     cat_A         both   both     15
    123     cat_B         both   both     45
```

Comment: Gives the wrong answer when only one `type_1` value is present: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wnpPiMphqPm21P7dkheuBy/1

Comment: @Nick have updated my answer. In assumption that it will have no duplicated and have only two categories `A` and `B`.

Comment: You should update your demo link too. Personally though, I think there are too many assumptions required to properly answer this question. Until OP updates the question pretty much everything will be a guess...

Comment: @zealous Your assumption is correct. Type_1 has only two categories A and B. Also, there are no duplicates. Thanks!

Comment: @user11035754 . . . A subquery is unnecessary.  This is more complicated than necessary -- and requires much more processing.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use aggregation:

```
select category_id, category,
       (case when min(Type_1) <> max(Type_2) then 'Both' else min(type_1) end) as type_1,
       Type_2,
       sum(no_of_items) as no_of_items
from t
where type_2 = 'both'
group by category_id, category, Type_2;
```